# Not able to install simple-graphics

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I tried to install simple-graphics using following command:

```
chicken-install simple-graphics
```

However, after running and installing files for some time, it ended in following error:

```
....
....
 sdl-base located at /tmp/temp95d8.5948/sdl-base
checking platform for `sdl-base' ...
checking dependencies for `sdl-base' ...
checking platform for `clojurian' ...
checking dependencies for `clojurian' ...
checking platform for `cairo' ...
checking dependencies for `cairo' ...
install order:
("cairo"
 "clojurian"
 "sdl-base"
 "matchable"
 "doodle"
 "setup-helper"
 "foreigners"
 "stty"
 "srfi-71"
 "miscmacros"
 "parley"
 "simple-graphics")
installing cairo:0.1.16 ...
changing current directory to /tmp/temp95d8.5948/cairo
  '/usr/bin/csi' -bnq -setup-mode -e "(require-library setup-api)" -e "(import setup-api)" -e "(setup-error-handling)" -e "(extension-name-and-version '(\"cairo\" \"0.1.16\"))" 'cairo.setup'
Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'cairo' found

Error: (string-parse-start+end) bad argument type - not a string: #!eof


Error: shell command terminated with nonzero exit code
17920
"'/usr/bin/csi' -bnq -setup-mode -e \"(require-library setup-api)\" -e \"(import...
```

I am using Debian Stable Linux.

I checked about 'cairo' and I have following packages installed:

```
libcairo-perl           1.106-1build1   1.106-1build1   1.106-1build1   install
libpango-perl           1.227-1         1.227-1         1.227-1         install
poppler-utils           0.41.0-0ubuntu1.1       0.41.0-0ubuntu1.1       0.41.0-0ubuntu1.1       install
python-cairo            1.8.8-2         1.8.8-2         1.8.8-2         install
python-gi-cairo         3.20.0-0ubuntu1 3.20.0-0ubuntu1 3.20.0-0ubuntu1 install
python-scour            0.32-1          0.32-1          0.32-1          install
python3-cairo           1.10.0+dfsg-5build1     1.10.0+dfsg-5build1     1.10.0+dfsg-5build1     install
python3-gi-cairo        3.20.0-0ubuntu1 3.20.0-0ubuntu1 3.20.0-0ubuntu1 install
```

I tried to install libcairo2 but I got following message:

```
libcairo2 is already the newest version (1.14.6-1).
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

### Edit:

I installed libcairo2-dev and then it ran further. However, now it terminated with following error:

```
...
...
installing sdl-base:0.1 ...
changing current directory to /tmp/tempeeb8.15805/sdl-base
  '/usr/bin/csi' -bnq -setup-mode -e "(require-library setup-api)" -e "(import setup-api)" -e "(setup-error-handling)" -e "(extension-name-and-version '(\"sdl-base\" \"0.1\"))" 'sdl-base.setup'
sh: 1: sdl-config: not found

Error: (string-split) bad argument type - not a string: #!eof


Error: shell command terminated with nonzero exit code
17920
"'/usr/bin/csi' -bnq -setup-mode -e \"(require-library setup-api)\" -e \"(import...
```

I tried installing sdl-base but it did not succeed:

```
$ sudo chicken-install sdl-base
retrieving ...
connecting to host "chicken.kitten-technologies.co.uk", port 80 ...
requesting "/henrietta.cgi?name=sdl-base&mode=default" ...
reading response ...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 14 Mar 2017 17:40:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.5.36 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain
reading chunks ....
reading files ...
  ./sdl-base.meta
  ./heap.scm
  ./keysym.scm
  ./timer.scm
  ./sdl-base-foreign-types-include.scm
  ./sdl-base.scm
  ./sdl-base.setup
  ./test-heap.scm
 sdl-base located at /tmp/tempf3a9.15940/sdl-base
checking platform for `sdl-base' ...
checking dependencies for `sdl-base' ...
install order:
("sdl-base")
installing sdl-base:0.1 ...
changing current directory to /tmp/tempf3a9.15940/sdl-base
  '/usr/bin/csi' -bnq -setup-mode -e "(require-library setup-api)" -e "(import setup-api)" -e "(setup-error-handling)" -e "(extension-name-and-version '(\"sdl-base\" \"0.1\"))" 'sdl-base.setup'
sh: 1: sdl-config: not found

Error: (string-split) bad argument type - not a string: #!eof


Error: shell command terminated with nonzero exit code
17920
"'/usr/bin/csi' -bnq -setup-mode -e \"(require-library setup-api)\" -e \"(import...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the `libcairo-dev` package, which contains the header files and pkg-config information. chicken-install needs to compile the cairo egg and link it against libcairo.  The error you get is because `pkg-config --cflags cairo` returns an error.

Comment: It want to install all these files for this: libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libexpat1-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libglib2.0-dev libice-dev libpixman-1-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev
  libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxrender-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
  x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xext-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev

Comment: I installed libcairo-dev but still there is problem. Please see edit in my question above.

Comment: Here too, you'll need to install the development version of the library. That's `libsdl-dev`.